# Getting Junit5 test cases to run in Spring STS 4

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, junit5

I have a Java Spring Boot project setup in STS4 and test cases written in Junit5 that I want to run from the IDE. But I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher.execute(Lorg/junit/platform/launcher/TestPlan;[Lorg/junit/platform/launcher/TestExecutionListener;)V
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

pom.xml looks very normal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo-junit</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>demo-junit</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.lognet</groupId>
      <artifactId>grpc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.spotnana</groupId>
      <artifactId>proto</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
      <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Non Spring -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
      <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And I have added only a simple testcase:

```
package com.spotnana.obt.supplier.sabre.air.services;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class SimpleTest {

  @Test
  void contextLoads() {}
}
```

The same configuration if I put into a new project works, in my same IDE, but there is something with the current project/IDE setup.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before with IntelliJ. I fixed it by adding the following dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I believe this is only temporary whilst the bug gets fixed but haven't looked into it since...